Why did the Polaris Dawn EVAers keep their feet inside the capsule? Were they not tethered?
According to Wikipedia's regularly updated Polaris Dawn: Events:

Since the Crew Dragon lacks an airlock, the entire capsule was depressurized during the EVA, exposing all crew members to the vacuum of space, though only two partially exited the spacecraft. Depressurization of the capsule took about 30 minutes. Isaacman went first, spending seven minutes and 56 seconds outside. Gillis went next, spending seven minutes and 15 seconds outside. From hatch open to hatch close the EVA took about 26 minutes and 40 seconds. During the EVA, Isaacman and Gillis performed several tests of their suit mobility including trials of hand/body control, vertical movement, and using a foot restraint, only their lower legs were still inside the spacecraft.

Question:  Why did the Polaris Dawn EVAers keep their feet inside? Were they not tethered? Were they told not to, or were they given the option but decided against it?

An umbilical provided life support for the suits, an extra tether was not necessary.

Partially because the suits are soft, hence it bloats in vacuum. This makes it very hard for the astronauts to move their arms and legs. A soft suit always try to settle to the shape of its largest volume, and any attempt to make it into any other shape would take great effort. The astronauts looks relax and comfortable but in fact they can hardly move at all. Had they been fully outside the spacecraft, they might repeat the Voskhod-2 incident.

@user3528438 - what happened with Voskhod 2 is that Leonov reentered the inflatable airlock head-first against protocol, then got stuck turning around to close the hatch, forcing him to reduce his suit pressure so that he could move as needed. In theory a spacesuit could become so stiff that any movement is nearly impossible, stranding an astronaut outside as sort of a human version of a mylar balloon. However the spacesuits were thoroughly tested in a vacuum chamber, so that would be highly unlikely.  Even if it was that stiff they would realize the problem before they left the capsule

I suspect the issue was less that the suit could inflate enough to be immovable, more the risk of losing contact with the ship and tumbling, which could get hairy for a number of reasons. Not something they wanted to even get close to on the first civilian spacewalk. With the legs inside, if somebody slips or loses their grip, they're not going to lose control.

The Polaris Dawn "spacewalk" was not only the first private EVA, it was also the first test of a newly designed SpaceX spacesuit, which is much different than the launch/entry suit used on previous SpaceX missions. It was also a test of the Dragon capsule itself, which until now had never been completely depressurized in space and open to a vacuum. It was also a test of the  hatch, noting that the hatch had previously only been opened in a pressurized environment when docked to the International Space Station.
The new EVA suit is based on the SpaceX IVA (Intra-vehicular activity) suit, but it has several enhancements for mobility, protection, and it also includes an HUD information display in the helmet.
The goal of the test EVA was to evaluate how the suit manages the transition to a hard vacuum, the mobility of the suit, and how the suit handles the various thermal conditions that can be experienced during an EVA. All of these objectives could be met by doing a standup EVA without floating away from the capsule.

Jared Isaacman EVA, Polaris Dawn, September 2024
The astronauts were tethered, as seen in this view of Sarah Gillis as she began to pass through the hatch opening to begin her EVA.

Sarah Gillis exits the capsule, Polaris Dawn, September 2024
As explained by Jared Isaacman in an interview with Bill Harwood of CBS News:

Isaacman said iconic photos of White floating outside his Gemini capsule against the backdrop of Earth and space were inspirational, but he and Gillis ruled out floating free of the Crew Dragon. And that was by design.

"We're not going to be doing the Ed White float," Isaacman told CBS News before launch. "That might look cool, but it doesn't really help SpaceX learn a lot about the performance (of the spacesuit). It's not very useful or helpful for figuring out how to be able to work in a suit."

It can be noted that Isaacman's comments were specific to "floating" outside the capsule. It does not rule out the possiblity of future EVA tests which might occur which could involve performing various tasks while outside the spacecraft.

Early artwork produced for this mission showed them completely outside. I suspect their "views evolved" for some specific, unstated reason. https://static.independent.co.uk/2024/09/11/16/polaris-dawn-spacewalk-live-stream.jpg If I was paying all that money for a recreational EVA, I would sure want the real thing.

@OrganicMarble - Yes it would be interesting to know how the plan evolved. I would guess they realized at some point that the timeline would be too short. They followed a pretty strict schedule, Isaacman was outside the hatch for only eight minutes, Gillis for seven minutes. The total EVA time was counted as the beginning and ending of umbilical usage which was one hour and forty-five minutes. The main limiter seemed to be oxygen delivered through the umbilicals to four astronauts, which apparently uses separate tanks from the main ECLSS. SpaceX had to install an extra tank for the EVA.

To add a bit of nuance to the answer, the Dragon capsule didn't actually go to full vacuum. There was a slow release of oxygen while the hatch was open in order to keep a slight positive pressure in the cabin, in order to help keep any thruster fumes from entering the cabin, and I think maybe to expel any noxious gases that might be emitted in the interior due to the (near) vacuum conditions.

@StevePemberton Interesting -- the pressure number in the video stream was 0.0. Sure, 0.049 is not a "proper" vacuum .... do you know what the pressure actually was? And yes, it makes a lot of sense to keep any hydrazine (I think!?) from the thrusters out of the interior. The workers who have first contact with a landed capsule all wear hazmat suits until it has been hosed down and checked.

@Peter - it's something I heard in the livestream - CORE: "three to off reset is in progress". Commentator: "You just heard Arthur call up three to off reset, so we didn't use any of the forward thrusters while Jared was out there, we're re-enabling them putting us back in our perfect attitude before Sarah gets ready to go out the door. It's still not a perfect vacuum inside Dragon, it's an open loop system so oxygen is kind of getting dumped into the cabin as this is going on, so you got a higher pressure in Dragon than you have outside, so we're not worried about thruster pluming".
